# Invalid conversion from "const char*" to "char" error

Tags: c++

I wanted to post this because I was not really sure what issue I was having with a simple assignment statement.  I am doing a homework assignment that asks me to write structs and functions in a simple program to draw out shapes of ASCII characters.  Right now I am just trying to test the functions I have written, and I am trying to assign a value to the symbol element of a Circle struct just to test out the DrawShape function I wrote.  When I try to assign it a * char, I get an error message saying "error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'".  I will put the whole code in, though it is very long and unfinished.  Any help with this would be appreciated. The problem I am getting is right in the beginning of the main at "circle1.char = '*' "

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 26;
const int NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 81;
char drawSpace[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];

struct Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct Circle{
    Point center;
    int radius;
    char symbol;
    bool buffer[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
};

bool setCircleRadius(Circle &b, int r);
bool setCircleCenter(Circle &b, int x, int y);
bool moveCircle(Circle &b, int x, int y);
void drawCircle (Circle b);
void lineChars(Line a);
void circleChars(Circle b);
void drawShapes();

int main() {
    Circle circle1;
    circle1.radius = 5;
    circle1.symbol = "*";
    circle1.center.x = 40;
    circle1.center.y = 10;

    drawCircle(circle1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `"*"`, which is a string, instead of `'*'` which is a char.

Comment: Next time, post a SHORT (but complete) example of the problem...

Comment: I took the liberty of removing all the method implementations, as they weren't necessary.

Comment: I understand the double quotes were the wrong syntax, but I changed them to single quotes and the program still does not compile.

Comment: @user895387 and the error now is???

Comment: It just says Error 1.

ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Assignment 5] Error 1

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should be using single quotes for characters. Double quotes means you're using a (potentially single-character) string literal, which is represented as a `const char *` (pointer to constant character).

Correct syntax: `circle1.symbol = '*';`

Answer (score 9):

The problem is here:

```
circle1.symbol = "*";
```

`circle1.symbol` is defined as `char`, but you assign a string to it (an array of chars). What you need to do is

```
circle1.symbol = '*';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your definition of `Circle` says that `symbol` is a `char`, yet you try to assign it a string literal of type `char[2]`:

```
circle1.symbol = "*";
```

Instead, you should be assigning it a `char`:

```
circle1.symbol = '*';
```

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
circle1.symbol = "*";
```

You need:

```
circle1.symbol = '*';
```

Answer (score 1):

The "symbol" member of your Circle struct is defined as a single char. Although it looks like you are assigning a char, you are actually assigning a string or char* of length 1. The difference: char a = 'a'; char *a = "a"; It's all in the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a single char is not written with double quites but with single quotes, i.e. `'*'`, not `"*"`. Actually "*" is an array of *two* chars, the first one being `'*'` and the second one being `'\0'` to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is at the line `circle1.symbol = "*";`.
`"*"` is a `const char *`
`symbol` (of your struct) is a `char`
Try: `circle1.symbol = '*';`